# Prove that there is no continuous and bijektive function with: $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for n > 1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have checked out some similar questions like:

[Proving there is no continuous function $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that is onto](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236813/proving-there-is-no-continuous-function-f-0-1-rightarrow-mathbb-r-that-i)

Unfortunately I'm still struggling with this problem. My idea was that I should show that the function is neither surjectiv nor injectiv. On the other side I was thinking about the set $f(\mathbb R^{n}\setminus \{0\} )$ to check out the continuity of the function. Really would apprecaite your helps.

Comment: Very easy consequence of connectedness of $\mathbb R^{n}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Can u eventually go into more details? Unfortunately I'm still struggling with this exercise

Comment: Late, but $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$ is connected, so $f(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\})$ is connected by continuity. Now this set cannot be a bounded interval, since we will violate surjectivity. So $f(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\})$ must be all of $\mathbb{R}$. But what happens for $f(\mathbf{0})$?